# Convert array of array indices to value in multidimensional array of dynamic size

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indices

i have an array as below :

```
test[
0 => 0,
1 => 2 ,
2 => 0,
3 => 2
]
```

the above array values are a representation on index of a larger array , so i need to covert the values to index of another array which will map the larger array as to achive below :

```
test2[0][2][0][2]
```

i tried :

```
$test3= array_flip ( $test )
```

works ok but is not convinient as to collisions as i dont have controll of the array , any help ?

Comment: You're trying to turn array of elements into arrays. In other words you're trying to create a nested array. There is no built in php function to dot his. You have to write it yourself.

Comment: `test2[test[0]][test[1]][test[2]][test[3]]` not work?

Comment: @JamesPaterson that will work but i dont know the lenght of array as its dynamic

Comment: Ok - Working on a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after head  i came up with below function which served my purpose :

```
$mainarray = [

0 => [
   0 =>[
      0 => [
         0 => 'one' ,
         1 => 'two' ,
         2 => 'three' ,
         3 => 'four'
      ],

      1 => [
         0 => 'one' ,
         1 => 'two' ,
         2 => 'three' ,
         3 => 'four'
      ]


   ]
]

]
```

Then this array below has the values as the index of the `$mainarray` above of what i want to get lets say `one` as above ,

```
$arraywithseacrhindex = [
0 => 0 , 
1 => 0 ,
2 => 0 ,
3 => 0 ,
]
```

Solution :

```
$array = $mainarray ;
$arr = $arraywithseacrhindex ;
$counter= count($arr)-1 ;
$result = array() ;
for($i=0; $i< $counter; $i++) {

    if(empty( $result ) )
    {
        // first loop to put $result at per with $array
        $result[$arr[$i]] = $array[$arr[$i]]  ; 
    }else{
            // this is the trick of the solution
            $cResult = current($result);
            unset($result);
            $result = array() ;
            $result[$arr[$i]] = $cResult[$arr[$i]]  ; 




    }

}

var_dump($result);
```

Hope it helps someone in future .

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayToIndex($array,$index) {
        $element = $array;
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($index); $i++) {
                    $element = $element[$index[$i]];
            }
            return $element;
    }
$test = [[[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]],[[[5],[6]],[[7],[8]]]];
$index = [0,1,0,0];
echo arrayToIndex($test,$index);
```

Here's a function that implements the behaviour you asked for. `$array` is the array to search into, and `$index` is the array of indexes. I suggest you play around with this example and see how each value is retrieved.

Live example: http://ideone.com/fork/BzCjcK

Comment: returns 3 , my end game is to get an array index representation as in `$index` in your example

Comment: This is working off the test data `$test` and `$index`. You'll need to copy just the function and call the function as `arrayToIndex($test2,$test)` in your OP example. It returns three because that is the element at `$test[0][1][0][0]`.

Comment: again , `$test2` is the end result of values of `$test1` , i have know idea what `$test2` is i need to get `$test2` from values of `$test`